# sortable list trigger is a specific object

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

So I have a normal jQueryUI Sortable List IE: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#default

However I would like the drag(or sort) event only to be triggered when the user clicks on a specific object inside my list item.  For the sake of the example lets say the arrows in the link I provide would trigger the drag event but clicking on the text wouldn't.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the handle option

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-handle